# binding do not work in C# WPF with oracle

Tags: c#, wpf, oracle, xaml, datagrid

I am using `DataGrid` control from `WPF` to present data from `Oracle` database. I wrote these lines:

XAML file:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
      Height="446" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="16,63,0,0" Name="systemDataGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="636">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding  ID}" Header="ID" MaxWidth="50" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding SYSTEM_NAME}" Header="Name" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding SYSTEM_DESC}" Header="Description"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding SYSTEM_CREATED}" Header="Created" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

CS file:

```
string sqlStr = "select ID, System_Name, System_Desc, System_Created from system";
OracleDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(sqlStr, db.Connection);
DataSet systemDataSet = new DataSet();
dataAdapter.Fill(systemDataSet);
if(systemDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    systemDataGrid.ItemsSource = systemDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
}
```

But the data from database cannot be displayed right there except the ID. And there is only ID shown if I turn off AutoGenerateColumns.

Sorry that I cannot post image. Please view it at https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z91C.png

The field names in `Oracle` is like `SYSTEM_NAME`, `SYSTEM_DESC` etc. And I have tried `{Binding SYSTEMNAME}` `{Binding SYSTEM_NAME}` `{Binding Path=SYSTEM_NAME}` etc, no one works.

Is there something wrong with my code, or it's the underscore in the field name?

---

### Update:

If I use `"select ID, System_Name systemname, System_Desc systemdesc, System_Created systemcreated from system";`, `{Binding SYSTEMNAME}` works fine, so there is definitely
something wrong with the underscore, but how?

Thank you for any information.

### Update:

It turns out that I was using `{Binding System_Name}` as the field name in SQL when I got nothing, and it worked if use `{Binding SYSTEM_NAME}`. Thank you guys and sorry for my mistake.

#### You have to use all upper case.

Comment: dont know that technology, but your are missing the underscores, and case might be also an issue

Comment: @thumbmunkeys I've tried all these with underscore, and every case. I personally think the underscore is "change" or something, 'cause the auto generated columns' header is without underscore.

Comment: What gets displayed with AutoGenerateColumns = true? This might hint you on the right binding names

Comment: @user3455395 the picture linked by the url shows the auto generated columns, and the headers have a letter underlined instead of underscore.

Comment: If you pause and debug: what is systemDataGrid.ItemsSource bound to? Perhaps the naming convention is not the same for the information you are trying to access.

Comment: @user999999928 `systemDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView.Table.Rows[0]["system_name"]` does have the value, but cannot be obtained by the `DataGridTextColumn `. Is there some strategy with underscore in xaml?

Comment: "but cannot be obtained by the DataGridTextColumn" Is DataGridTextColumn actually showing null for the value or something? Have you set a break point to it and inspected its value? I have a feeling it may be binding correctly, but it isn't being updated when you throw the new items source at it. Or its just a wrong name.

Comment: @user999999928 Yes, It's the name, SYSTEM_NAME works, but System_Name don't.